# No scientific in ybar of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm wondering how to disable scietific notation in lables of ybar. here is the tex code:

```
\begin{axis}
 [width=6cm, height=6cm,  
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=5pt,
        ylabel=Cost,
    x=2cm,
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={ anchor=mid west, rotate=90},
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E},
    axis lines*=left,
    ]
\addplot coordinates { (A,12398) (B,31814) (C,30833) (D,72290) (E,9078)}; %Greedy
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: And the chart...]

Comment: Is your question answered by [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69978/disable-scientific-notation-for-y-axis-and-data-in-pgfplots?rq=1)?

Comment: No. I tried that answer as the basis, but It does not work :(

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9803/how-do-you-remove-the-axis-multiplier/9847#9847

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scaled y ticks=false`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
 [width=6cm, height=6cm,  
    ybar=5pt,
        ylabel=Cost,
    x=2cm,
    ymin=0,
    xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={ anchor=mid west, rotate=90},
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E},
    axis lines*=left,
        scaled y ticks=false,
    ]
\addplot coordinates { (A,12398) (B,31814) (C,30833) (D,72290) (E,9078)}; %Greedy
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]