# Horizontal or Vertical Bar chart with small coordinate values

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

Trying to draw a bar chart either horizontal or vertical using following code

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\definecolor{Color}{HTML}{2B83BA}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-.5,0)}]
\foreach  \l/\x/\c[count=\y] in {L1-dCache-Read-Miss/0.225701966/Color, 
    L1-iCache-Read-Miss/-0.066446811/Color, 
    L3-Cache-Read-Miss/0.036589862/Color, 
    L3-Cache-Write-Miss/0.010495496/Color}
{\node[left] at (0,\y) {\l};
    \fill[\c] (0,\y-.4) rectangle (\x,\y+.4);
    \node[right] at (\x, \y) {\x};}
\draw (-.5,0) -- (.5,0);
\foreach \x in {-.1, -.09, -.08, ..., .2}
{\draw (\x,.2) -- (\x,0) node[below] {\x};}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,4.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Results are not as expected because of extremely small values. Expected output is as in the attached image[image]

Comment: Use `xscale`  and `yscale` to scale the tikzpicture. Or just use `pgfplots` [barplot](http://www.pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/tag/bar-plots/)

Comment: I got this error: `! LaTeX Error: File "svjour3.cls" not found.` Please make your code compileable.

Comment: @AndréC You have to use Springer document class to compile it

Comment: Where do we find it?

Comment: If the problem isn't related to the class (which I think is the case here), you might as well use `\documentclass{article}` for the example.

Comment: @AndréC You can find it here https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am preparing a manuscript for Springer.

Comment: Yes, but the problem you're describing is about TikZ, not the `svjour` class, and not any interaction between TikZ and `svjour`. It's likely that a solution with `article` will work just as well with `svjour`. As suggested above using `pgfplots` for this might be a good idea, here is one somewhat similar example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160819

Comment: In your graph you have inverted the role of the abscissa and ordinate. What you called `\x` is not an abscissa, it's actually an ordinate. And vice versa; `\y` is actually an abscissa.