# Pgfplots mixes scientific and decimal labels as plot ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, ticks, decimal-number

I am creating a simple plot like this

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=14cm,
]
\addplot table{%
-0.02       0.976511902149045
0.02        0.974250140430107
0.06        0.92759014496851
0.10        0.881800630168479
0.14        0.776610110223684
0.18        0.543609593143291
0.22        0.259832897473002
0.26        0.0765836982036106
0.30        0.0158062920127819
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

For some reason the created plot mixes decimal and scientific notation (for -0.05 and 0.05) in the tick labels. How can I get all ticks to be displayed as decimals?

[image: created plot]

Comment: `\begin{axis}[%
width=14cm,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
]` should give you the desired result.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?) questions: [Disable scientific notation for Y-axis and data in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69978/134144), [How to prevent pgfplots from using the 10^n notation for axis ticks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29926/134144) and [How do you remove the axis multiplier?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9803/134144)

Comment: @leandriis thank you so much for your help. It works great.